# sumar resultados de arrayList

Tags: java, arraylist

Buen día, tengo un código que imprime 3 columas de un archivo, en la tercera columna vienen el precio de unos servicios, quiero hacer que el programa también sume todos los precios y los imprima.

este es el código

```
 try {
    System.out.println("... Leemos el contenido del archivo ...");
    s = new Scanner(fichero);

            List<String[]> datos = new ArrayList<String[]>();
            int i =0;

            while (s.hasNextLine()) {
                String linea = s.nextLine(); 
                datos.add(linea.split("\\|"));

                String[] x = datos.get(i);
                if(x[5].equals("4")){

                    System.out.print(x[5] + " "+ x[15] + "       "+ x[29] + "\n");
                    //System.out.println("");

                }

                i+=1;

            }
  }
```

aquí sólo imprime las tres columnas...

gracias por su ayuda

Answer (score 0):

Para sumar todos los valores podes hacer lo siguiente

```
try {
    System.out.println("... Leemos el contenido del archivo ...");
    s = new Scanner(fichero);

            List<String[]> datos = new ArrayList<String[]>();
            int i =0;

            while (s.hasNextLine()) {
                String linea = s.nextLine(); 
                datos.add(linea.split("\\|"));

                String[] x = datos.get(i);
                int total += Integer.parseInt(datos.get(i)); // <-- Podes usarlo donde necesites mostrarlo
                if(x[5].equals("4")){

                    System.out.print(x[5] + " "+ x[15] + "       "+ x[29] + "\n");
                    System.out.println("Total: "+total);

                }

                i+=1;

            }
  }
```